# Spark memory fraction Parameter

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-manager

I am using Cloudera distribution of Hadoop and the Spark2 version that is used is 2.2. I was searching for memory management parameters that are present inside "Memory Management" section of the below link:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/configuration.html

However, I don't see these configuration parameters inside spark2> Configuration link of Cloudera Manager.

I think there is some gap in my understanding. Please suggest where to look for if these parameters are to be manually changed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Spark configuration]

Hi,

I have provided the parameters of memory tuning in this way in spark configuration of cloudera Manager. What happens is, if you save this then the spark-defaults.conf file gets updated in the server and upon restart of Spark2 service you get the benefit of the configuration change.

Hope it helps.